# I am trying to figure out how to get the 'Pause' and 'Stop' button to work on my timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am trying to figure out how to get my timer to work properly. The timer itself works however the 'Pause' and 'Stop' button don't seem to respond.

This is the code that i have so far:

```
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
      start = document.getElementById('start'),
      pause = document.getElementById('pause'),
      stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
      seconds = 0,
      minutes = 0,
      hours = 0,
      t;

    function add() {
      seconds++;
      if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
          minutes = 0;
          hours++;
        }
      }

      h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") +
        ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

      timer();
    }

    function timer() {
      t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
    }
    timer();        

//START BUTTON
    $("#start").on("click", function() {
      clearTimeout(t);
      timer();
    });
```

Having trouble getting a response for this:

```
//PAUSE BUTTON
    $("#pause").on("click", function() {
      clearTimeout(t);
    });
//STOP BUTTON
    $("#stop").on("click", function() {
      h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
      seconds = 0;
      minutes = 0;
      hours = 0;
    });
```

Comment: Have you verified that the pause/stop click handlers are executing (with a console log or something)?  The stop click isn't doing anything with the timer, so not sure how that would function as a 'stop'.

Answer (score 0):

this fiddle works:
https://jsfiddle.net/0a41am3v/

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;
var t;

function add()
{
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60)
    {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) 
        {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") +
        ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}

function timer()
{
      t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}


$("#start").on("click", function() {
        $("#start").empty().append("start");
        clearTimeout(t);
        timer();
    });

$("#pause").on("click", function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    $("#start").empty().append("resume");
});

$("#stop").on("click", function() {
    $("#start").empty().append("start");
    clearInterval(t);
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
 });
```